# Connecting to remote Emacs with X forwarding

Tags: emacs, ssh, emacs24

I have a desktop always running at work with Emacs open. I'd like to remotely connect to the process on my computer at work, and am able to do that with ssh and emacsclient. But I can't cleanly exit without causing the original process to crash. I'm doing the following to connect to an emacs frame with a server name of 'foo':

`$ ssh -XC ej@tower`

`$ emacsclient -s foo -e "(make-frame-on-display \"$DISPLAY\")"`

This works, however I can't find any way to kill the ssh connection without crashing the original process. It seems like some background process is still connected, and killing it (which occurs after killing the remote connection) brings down everything. Does anyone know a better way to do this or a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I was running into stemmed from [a Gtk+ bug](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715) which caused Emacs to crash when an X11 connection was unexpectedly lost.

Recompiling to use a different X toolkit solved the issue.

```
./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid
```

Answer (score 2):

I know what you're talking about, and rather curiously I can't recreate it on my current system. I'm not sure why that is. However...

The classic workaround to avoid this is to start processes in a sub-shell:

```
$ (emacs &)
```

rather than:

```
$ emacs &
```

There are also things like `nohup` and `disown` which you may or may not have available, but the sub-shell approach is simple and has always been reliable for me.

You could also start the processes from the local side of the connection:

```
$ ssh -XC ej@tower -f emacs --daemon=foo
$ ssh -XC ej@tower -f emacsclient -s foo -c
```

Comment: The (emacs &) solution didn't work for me. nohup and disown also didn't fix this issue. However, I got an error when I tried your `ssh -XC ej@tower -f emacs --daemon=foo` suggestion.  "   Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem."  I'm trying that fix now

Comment: After recompiling my emacs with  --with-x-toolkit=lucid I don't run into this issue. So the Gtk+ was definitely the culprit, and your suggestions made that easily apparent, thanks! If you edit your answer to reference the bug I'll mark your answer as accepted

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood the nature of the problem after all. Please do post your solution as a new answer, which you can then accept.

Comment: Done, thanks again for your response. Wouldn't have fixed this without it